# Creating site alias issue

Tags: drush

Using [examples/example.site.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drush-ops/drush/master/examples/example.site.yml), I created a self.site.yml file which seemed to work fine.

I get the correct values when running `drush site:alias @self.stage`, but when I try to run `drush command @self.stage` I get this error message.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in ... /vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/DependencyInjection.php:59

Comment: Try `drush @stage`.

Comment: Yes @stage did work for the self.site.yml but I was more interested in multisite setup. When I started moving the alias files to the /.drush folder instead of a folder i created called /drush things started to work better.

Comment: However my goal is to run drush commands on all of them at once ie @sites I do not the correct way to do this.

Comment: Yes something like that seems to be the correct way to accomplish this. https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3019